# PHP Class to draw a competition playoff table in HTML

Tags: php, html, class

I'm looking for a PHP class that would draw me (by fetching data from a mysql table) a competition playoff table in HTML similar to what they do on wikipedia (see under the "Bracket" section):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009%E2%80%9310_UEFA_Europa_League_knockout_phase

Any input?

Comment: This looks simple enough to write on your own.

Answer (score 1):

firstly it totally depends on the structure of your database table.

you need to understand that you have to have children and parent and sibling tracking in your rows to tell what row belongs to what parent row.

so that if you first select all the rows where they do not ahve a parent row attached, then you have your root elements, witch in your case "Round of 32", then what you have to do is then select all the rows that are a parent of `Club Brugge,Everton,Galatasaray,Atlético Madrid......` so that they can append the parent dataset, and so forth to you have no elements left

Comment: -1: the question wasn't about database design

Comment: so why did you tag it mysql ?